# Capture device (microphone) detected by alsa but not pipewire

Tags: alsa, microphone, pipewire

I have an issue where audacity and arecord are able to receive input from the microphone while the rest of the system cannot, instead it seems that it just duplicates the audio output.

My system is EndeavourOs with kernel `6.2.13-arch1-1`. However, I also tested my microphone on a liveusb Linux Mint, which also did not work. My system seems to run pipewire with plugins for alsa, pulseAudio and wireplumber for sound managment.

With both arecord (`arecord --duration=5 --format=dat --device=hw:3,2 test-mic.wav`) and audacity I have to use card 3, device 2 to get mic input.

I also tried to look at qpwgraph program, and it does contain only one capture device, which when recorded just duplicates the sound output. So it seems like pipewire does not see the correct capture device which alsa sees. I am also able to control the microphone with alsamixer.

A lot of posts recommend unlocking the microphone channels and muting one of them, however it did not help in my case.

I also tried to change profile in pavucontrol to "pro audion" but it did not help.

I can use the microphone in some apps (for now only arecord and audacity), and it perfectly works on Windows in the same setup. However, for some reason, it does not want to work on Linux. I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Relevant info:

The headphones have a combo-jack and connected through a splitter to a motherboard (MAG B650 TOMAHAWK WIFI).

```
❯ arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

```
❯ arecord -L
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
lavrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Libav/FFmpeg Library
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pipewire
    PipeWire Sound Server
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
speex
    Plugin using Speex DSP (resample, agc, denoise, echo, dereverb)
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
default
    Default ALSA Output (currently PipeWire Media Server)
usbstream:CARD=NVidia
    HDA NVidia
    USB Stream Output
usbstream:CARD=Generic_1
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
front:CARD=Generic
    Front output / input
surround21:CARD=Generic
    2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
surround40:CARD=Generic
    4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
surround41:CARD=Generic
    4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround50:CARD=Generic
    5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
surround51:CARD=Generic
    5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
surround71:CARD=Generic
    7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
usbstream:CARD=Generic
    HD-Audio Generic
    USB Stream Output
sysdefault:CARD=Audio
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=Audio,DEV=0
    USB Audio, USB Audio
    Front output / input
usbstream:CARD=Audio
    USB Audio
    USB Stream Output
```

```
❯ inxi -Axxx
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GA104 High Definition Audio vendor: ZOTAC
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus-ID: 1-6:3 pcie: chip-ID: 0db0:422d
    class-ID: 0300 speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.1
    chip-ID: 10de:228b class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Rembrandt Radeon High Definition Audio
    vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s
    lanes: 16 bus-ID: 0f:00.1 chip-ID: 1002:1640 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h/19h HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 0f:00.6 chip-ID: 1022:15e3 class-ID: 0403
  Device-4: Micro Star USB Audio type: USB
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  API: ALSA v: k6.2.13-arch1-1 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: sndiod v: N/A status: off
  Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.70 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active 3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
    4: pw-jack type: plugin
```

The last messages are marked in yellow, so I suppose they are warnings, I also tried to google for it to see if anything pops up, but I got nothing:

```
❯ systemctl --user status --now pipewire.service
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2023-04-29 02:37:46 CEST; 9s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 21616 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 37369)
     Memory: 8.5M
        CPU: 38ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─21616 /usr/bin/pipewire

Apr 29 02:37:46 tower systemd[826]: Started PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Apr 29 02:37:46 tower pipewire[21616]: mod.rt: Can't find org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop. Is xdg-desktop-portal running?
Apr 29 02:37:46 tower pipewire[21616]: mod.rt: found session bus but no portal
```

And some cpu info in case this is relevant:

```
❯ lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         48 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  12
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-11
Vendor ID:               AuthenticAMD
  Model name:            AMD Ryzen 5 7600 6-Core Processor
    CPU family:          25
    Model:               97
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  6
    Socket(s):           1
    Stepping:            2
    Frequency boost:     enabled
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:  66%
    CPU max MHz:         5169,3350
    CPU min MHz:         3000,0000
    BogoMIPS:            7602,37
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clf
                         lush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm cons
                         tant_tsc rep_good amd_lbr_v2 nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf 
                         rapl pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt
                          aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm ss
                         e4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core 
                         perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc mwaitx cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate ssbd mba pe
                         rfmon_v2 ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid 
                         cqm rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb avx51
                         2cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occ
                         up_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local avx512_bf16 clzero irperf xsaveerptr rdp
                         ru wbnoinvd cppc arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flus
                         hbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif x2a
                         vic v_spec_ctrl avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq
                          avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid overflow_recov succor smc
                         a fsrm flush_l1d
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        AMD-V
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   192 KiB (6 instances)
  L1i:                   192 KiB (6 instances)
  L2:                    6 MiB (6 instances)
  L3:                    32 MiB (1 instance)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          1
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-11
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         Not affected
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Not affected
  Retbleed:              Not affected
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Retpolines, IBPB conditional, IBRS_FW, STIBP always-on, RSB fil
                         ling, PBRSB-eIBRS Not affected
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Not affected
```